# How can i access a already existing UIPickerView from code

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uipickerview

I have this PickerView already existing UIPickerView in my storyboard with hidden set to YES, I'd like to make this picker visible when my button is pressed but i'm clueless about how to do this.

I've tried getting this ViewController through it's identification but i was unable to find this property on xcode, I'm not even sure UIPickerView has an identifier...

Here's the code from my action that should be executed after the button is pressed.

```
-(IBAction)actionButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    isFeelingPicker = FALSE;
    isActivityPicker = TRUE;

    UIPickerView* picker;

    picker = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Picker"];


    [picker setHidden:NO];


}
```

By the way, I'm really new to IOS so there should be many mistakes there x_x

EDIT:

Picker's numberOfRowsInComponent

```
-(NSInteger) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:        (NSInteger)component{
    if(isActivityPicker){
        return activities_.count;
    }
    else if(isFeelingPicker){
        return feelings_.count;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: when you drag a picker view to your storyboard, you ought to make an outlet for it (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5v5wXmAhhU). Then, in your code, you can use this outlet to perform any your action which you want.

Comment: Awesome ! It worked :) Thanks a lot :D However now I have another problem, since I'm defining the actual value of these booleans (isActivityPicker and isFeelingPicker) inside my buttonPress (which happens AFTER the view is loaded and my PickerView numberOfRowsInComponent is being called from inside my viewDidLoad, my picker is always appearing empty... how can i populate my picker AFTER my buttonPressed ?

Comment: Managed to make it work ! I've used pickerView.reloadAllComponents !

Comment: Correction, my picker's protocol required methods aren't inside my viewDidLoad ! My bad '-'